# Integrate arccos(sin(x)) from 0 to pi/4

Tags: integration

This was a problem a friend recently me asked to do. Seeing this integral, I immediately thought of angle addition formulas as integration by parts seemed too tedious to use. So I let $x = u + pi/2$ as that converts the $sin(x)$ term into a $cos(u)$ term and the $arccos(cos(u)) = u$. The integral of $u$ is trivial to compute. After plugging in the new bounds accordingly, I ended up getting $-3pi^2/32$ as my answer, but the actual answer was $3pi^2/32$. Which makes me wonder if my bounds we correct? I integrated $u$ from $-pi/2$ to $-pi/4$.

Comment: You must stand back and think: what angle has its cosine equal to the sine of Theta? Why is the function called the **co**sine?

Comment: Did I invalidate the given domain of arccos which is why I get the negative of the desired answer?

Comment: What is $\arccos(\sin(1^\circ))\,$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: I recommend graphing $\arccos(\sin(x))$ real quick... it'll help a ton ;)

Comment: I don't know inverse trig that well lol, I'm just wondering if I invalidated the domain of arccos?

Comment: Please: what is the *meaning* of arccos?

Comment: Undoes the cosine of an angle.

Comment: Can someone please help me solve this problem using the method I used. Would be very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: we have 
$$
\cos \alpha=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)
$$

so the correct substitution is
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{2}-u\qquad\rightarrow \qquad dx=-du
$$

Comment: But the important fact is that the integrand is $\frac\pi2-x$, no need to make a substitution.